# Overlaping text with radio buttons in bootstrap col

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have a radio button with .html added to it. But the result it's a overlap text with the radio button.

[Overlapping Radio buttons with text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjR32.jpg)

Also as you can see the text goes downward instead of covering all of the bootstrap col-4 , col-4, col-4.

```js
function addQAs() {
    randQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * library.length); //this is a nuber, dont forget!
    console.log(randQuestion);
    $("#question").html(library[randQuestion].question);
    $("#answer1").html(library[randQuestion].answer[0]);
    $("#answer2").html(library[randQuestion].answer[1]);
    $("#answer3").html(library[randQuestion].answer[2]);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="answer1" value="answer1" index="0">
                    <label for="answer1"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="answer2" value="answer2" index="1">
                    <label for="answer2"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="answer3" value="answer3" index="2">
                    <label for="answer3"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I havent tried any CSS for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add this css

```
.col-4 {
  position: relative;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px; // set as per your requirement
  top: 5px; // set as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.